# How to minify webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

hello I am learning webpack and I am trying to build a React App from scratch. Unfortunately, I am getting this error.

```
asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  bundle.js (792 KiB)
```

I messed around with the docs the entire day and I have come up with this webpack configs

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerNotifierPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-notifier-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js",
    },
    
    output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve("dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
    clean: true,
    chunkFilename: "chunk.[id].js",
    },

    module: {
    rules: [
        // typescript
        {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        },
        // js / jsx
        {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
            }
        },
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        },
        // css
        {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"], 
        },
        // images
        {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        },
    ]
    },
    resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    symlinks: false
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
    static: {
        directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    },
    port: 3000,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    open: true,

    },
    plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true,
        template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html")
    }),
    new ForkTsCheckerNotifierPlugin({
        title: "typescript",
        excludeWarnings: false
    })
    ],
    performance: {
    hints: "warning"
    },
    optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
    removeAvailableModules: false,
    removeEmptyChunks: false,
    splitChunks: {
         minSize: 10000,
         maxSize: 250000,
      }
    }
}
```

My app for now consists only of this two files

```
index.html

    1 <!DOCTYPE html>
    2 <html lang="en">
    3 <head>
    4         <meta charset="UTF-8">
    5         <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    6         <title>Portfolio</title>
    7 </head>
    8 <body>
    9     <div id="root"></div>
   10     <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
   11 </body>
   12 </html>
```

```
app.js
  1 import React from "react";
    2
    3 const App = () => <h1>Hello World</h1>;
    4 export default App;
```

```
index.js
   1 import React from "react";
>>  2 import { ReactDOM } from "react";
    3 import App from "./App";
    4
    5 ReactDOM.render(
    6     <App />,
    7     document.querySelector("#root")
    8 );
~
```

I genuinely do not understand how can my app be so huge. Could someone help?

here you can find also my package.json deps

```
"devDependencies": {
   22     "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
   23     "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
   24     "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.1",
   25     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
   26     "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
   27     "@types/node": "^18.8.5",
   28     "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
   29     "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
   30     "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
   31     "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
   32     "fork-ts-checker-notifier-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
   33     "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.2.13",
   34     "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
   35     "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
   36     "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
   37     "typescript": "^4.8.4",
   38     "webpack": "^5.74.0",
   39     "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
   40     "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
   41   },
   42   "dependencies": {
   43     "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
   44     "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
   45     "@mui/material": "^5.10.9"
   46   }
   47 }
```

Comment: I'm no wizard of webpack, but, if you take a look through `/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` they use `optimization: { minimize: true } }` with a fair amount of custom config too. Might not be all too helpful but it gives you somewhere to look

Comment: technically speaking webpack uses terser (a plugin) by default, which minimizes it by default. I'll keep looking though thanks for your suggestion

Comment: are your bundle.js files minimized at all?

Comment: I ran the command webpack --json which produces all the modules bundled. The size shows up to be 87MIB so I genuinely do not understand where those 700+mib come from. Maybe in this tool "https://webpack.github.io/analyse/#errors" they are not in dev mode, thus making a more efficient bundle. Don't know. I am also bundling all the necessary files (I am not including node_modules/)

Comment: Yea that certainly doesn't sound right, good luck with your endeavour :)

Comment: Remove minification/comments removal etc. and open your bundle.js in text editor to  see whats there.